# playframework 2.x logback logging only half working?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I added logging.xml file to my conf directory and I see the play log format change(good) BUT the level does not change to debug.  It seems to only obey the log levels set in application.conf which is very annoying.  I wanted to set up different levels in the logger.xml file but this file does not seem to work at all(it ignores the levels).  Is this intentional in play...?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %logger %method%n%level: %message%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this questionapplicable for Play 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: answer is in the title and I also tagged it with 2.0 (though I mean 2.x since I am using the most recent version).

Comment: Just to make sure: you have read this page: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SettingsLogger

Comment: no, I read this one which seems to be more up to date/reliable since it says use logger.xml and that link incorrectly says use application-logger.xml which doesn't work at all.... http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SettingsLogger

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file to configure logback is logger.xml

Remove logging properties in the application.conf file and you will have the configuration from the logger.xml file.

It work for Play 2.1.0.

Example at: https://github.com/fasar/Ingredienty/

Comment: they probably fixed it.  We ended up back porting to play 1.2.x as it was just much faster development wise.  The scala compiler was just way toooooo slow in that it was like rebooting tomcat which was the really cool thing about the playframework to begin with.

Comment: I don't think they fixed it.  I can config/logger.xml from the play console and it justs works.  If I "play dist" and build a standalone application, my standalone app never loads the logger.xml file that gets JARed up into it.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Play uses application-logger.xml instead of what the docs state. This issue is known but they didn't fix it... bugged me for hours. See: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1186